# What is the motivation behind tweaking a clubhead's loft?

Tags: equipment, golf

In a [video](http://www.pgatour.com/video.html/2013/07/15/equipment--how-to-build-sergio-garcia-s-driver) to build Sergio Garcia's driver, the equipment builder takes a clubhead with a stock loft of 10 degrees and tweaks it to have a final clubhead loft of 8.5 degrees.

**What is the motivation behind tweaking a clubhead's loft?** Are there advantages to tweaking a clubhead's loft (10 to 8.5) vs. using a stock loft (8.5 with no tweaking)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Wade Liles' wording in the video is confusing.

Non-adjustable drivers can be purchased with different amounts of loft.  For example, the [TaylorMade RocketBallz Stage 2 Tour Driver](http://taylormadegolf.ca/TaylorMade/RocketBallz-Stage-2-Tour-Driver/DW-JN997,en_CA,pd.html) can be purchased as either a 9˚ or 10.5˚ (the options are on the right-hand side).

There are no such options for adjustable drivers like the [TaylorMade R1](http://taylormadegolf.ca/TaylorMade/R1-Driver/DW-JN917,en_CA,pd.html) and [TaylorMade R1 TP](http://taylormadegolf.ca/TaylorMade/R1-TP-Driver/DW-JN919,en_CA,pd.html), they are sold as is and then can be adjusted (those models can range from 8˚ to 12˚).

So in the video when Wade says that Sergio likes 8.5, he grabs a 10˚ one from the drawer and then adjusts it to 8.5˚, but he could've grabbed any of the other heads.

To answer your question, there is no difference between tweaking a club vs using a stock loft.  The reason they tweak it in the video is because you can't have a 8.5˚ R1 any other way.

Comment: In my opinion, that's a bit disappointing...but I understand the reasons for manufacturing higher lofts. Average golfers have drivers with 13, 14 degrees of loft. For me, I hit the ball too high with anything over 9.5.

Comment: Is the cost price of influence?

Comment: So, are you saying that, essentially (that is: other than the printing), different lofted driver heads of the same model are identical?

Comment: yes, its the same as buying a hockey stick that comes with different curves for the blade.  Same stick, just the curves are shaped differently.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends I truly find that hard to believe. Of course, the question isn't in regards to having the same shaft, but about the clubhead itself. If all clubheads are made equal and just "manufactured" to accommodate for a specific loft....then is the listed loft "misleading"?

Comment: @edmastermind29 - No, because when the loft is printed on the clubhead, it does actually make a difference; a 9.5* head is the result of a different set of molds than a 10.5*, and the two will behave differently for different golfers. A strong swing is needed for a 9.5*, because the lower launch means that, all things being equal, it doesn't carry as far. But, that stronger swing now sends the ball out along the course instead of up in the air. For a 10.5*, it's the opposite; a slower swing will pop the ball in the air so that it stays there longer and so carries further.

Comment: However, with these new top-of-the-line adjustable heads in the R11 and R1, one head is shaped and constructed so that you can vary the launch angle by changing how the club fits to the shaft, and change the shape of the shot (draw/fade) by changing the weighting behind the face at the bottom of the clubhead. So, one head, made one way, can be anything from an 8.5 to an 11.5 loft, and anything from a Draw driver to a Tour driver, just by how it's configured.

Comment: That's huge, because the club can grow with you and adapt to you; usually you buy a 10.5* R-flex GI driver to get started, and as your swing speed improves you trade up to a 9.5* S-flex Tour driver. Here, the only thing you have to trade out is the shaft, from Regular to Stiff; the same clubhead can be reconfigured to do everything else.

Comment: @KeithS All things equal, in regards to clubheads itself, a 9.5° lofted clubhead is different from a 10.5° lofted clubhead? I understand and have seen adjustability, and find it rather interesting and innovative. I switched from a 10.5° lofted regular shaft driver to a 9.5° lofted stiff shaft driver because I was popping up my 10.5°.

Comment: Yes. The same swing, of a club of the same model, with the same shaft, but different loft angles, will cause exactly the behavior you saw; the higher loft will launch higher and have more backspin, so the ball gets longer hang time but doesn't travel along the ground as fast. The lower loft will launch lower, reducing backspin and overall height, but increasing the x-axis component of the ball's velocity (it travels along the ground faster).

Comment: Too string a swing, with a high-lofted driver, will cause the energy to be wasted sending the ball up in the air (too whippy a shaft causes other losses). Too weak a swing with a low-lofted driver (or a stiff shaft) reduces distance because the ball just doesn't fly long enough.